# SQL statement to count with a condition

Tags: sql

I am a beginner in SQL, and I need help to get the solution for this condition.

For each attraction, output the number of people visiting this attraction during 2013.

```
create table visitor( 
visitID         char(n),
name            char(n) not null,
primary key (visitID)
);

create table ticket(
ticketID        char(n),
ticketType      char(n),
day             int(n),
month           char(n),
year            int(n),
seasonID        char(n),
visitID         char(n),
primary key (ticketID), foreign key (seasonID) references seasonPerClass, foreign      
key (visitID) references visitor
);

create table attractionVisit(
attractionID        char(n),
ticketID        char(n),
foreign key (attractionID) references attraction, foreign key (ticketID) references    
ticket
);

create table attraction(
attractionID        char(n),
attractionName  char(n) not null,
primary key (attractionID)
);
```

I am unable to test my code, but so far I have

```
SELECT AttractionName, count(distinct VisitID)
FROM (Visitation NATURAL JOIN AttractionVisit)
WHERE year = 2013;
```

I don't know if this is right or not. Please help.

Comment: What rdbms do you have? what's with these `(n)`s everywhere? have any sample data?

Comment: in which table you are storing year?

Comment: I dont see a table by name `Visitation`

Answer (score 0):

You need a `group by` in your query:

```
SELECT AttractionName, count(distinct VisitID)
FROM (Visitation NATURAL JOIN AttractionVisit)
GROUP BY AttractionName
WHERE year = 2013;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select att.attractionName, count(att.attractionId) as count
from visitor v inner join ticket t on ( v.visitID = t.visitID)
inner join attractionVisit av on (t.ticketID = av.ticketID)
inner join attraction att on (av.attractionID = att.attractionID)
where t.year = 2013
group by att.attractionName`
```

Hope this is help.